# Create a process whose ruser and user are different

Tags: linux, perl, unix

Could anyone please help to find a way to create a process whose ruser and user are different? 
   Currently, I used the line

```
sudo su david -c ./test.pl
```

Then when I typed the following line to get the user and ruser

```
ps -eo pid,user,ruser,fname,pcpu,nice,stime,time | grep test.pl
10322   david   david test.pl 12.4 20 13:37:00 01:38
```

The user and ruser are still the same.
I need to create a process like the following sample:

```
ps -o user,ruser,comm -p 59515
    USER    RUSER COMMAND
    root csrethab xscreensaver
```

Any thoughts?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from within the perl script by setting the special [$< variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24UID).

Here is an example:

```
system("ps -eo pid,user,ruser,fname,pcpu,nice,stime,time | grep $$");
$< = 1000;
print "Changed\n";
system("ps -eo pid,user,ruser,fname,pcpu,nice,stime,time | grep $$");
```

This prints the following:

```
22460 root     root     perl      0.0   0 20:46 00:00:00
Changed
22460 root     jordan   perl      0.0   0 20:46 00:00:00
```

The only way to do this outside of the code is via setuid. The setuid bit is ignored in scripts in linux, so that is not possible from perl.

Comment: @user2142332 If you feel that this answer is correct, you can "accept" it by clicking the check next to the votes.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the sys::process module, which encapsulates this for you:

https://metacpan.org/pod/sys::process::user#SYNOPSIS

Comment: Looking at the code, all that appears to do is provide a very thin layer around `$>` and `$<`.